# (Dataflow) Apache Beam Python requirements.txt file not installing on workers

Tags: python, dependencies, python-import, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to run an Apache Beam pipeline on Google Dataflow. This pipeline reads data from Google BigQuery, adds a schema, converts it to a Dataframe, and performs a transformation on that dataframe using a third-party library (`scrubadub`).

From the Google Code CLI on GCP, I run:

```
/usr/bin/python /home/test_user/dataflow_beam_test.py --requirements_file /home/test_user/requirements.txt
```

Following the instructions [under "PyPi Dependencies" here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/), my requirements.txt file contains (among other packages):

```
scrubadub==2.0.0
```

I haven't been able to get the pipeline to install the third party Python library I'm working with (`scrubadub`) onto remote workers. I've verified this package works locally.

Here is the relevant code:

```
    with beam.Pipeline(argv=argv) as p:
        pcoll = (p | 'read_bq_view' >> 
        beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(query=BIGQUERY_SELECT_QUERY,use_standard_sql=True) 
        | 'ToRows' >> beam.Map(lambda x: beam.Row(id=x['id'], user_id=x['user_id'],query=x['query']))
        )
        df = beam_convert.to_dataframe(pcoll)
        df['query'] = df['query'].apply(lambda x: scrubadub.clean(x))
```

The last line in this code block is what causes the error (I've confirmed by commenting it out and running the pipeline successfully).

I've tried importing scrubadub at the top level of the file and as part of my `run()` function; both throw the same error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 826, in _import_module return __import__(import_name) ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrubadub'
```

Notably, it doesn't seem like `pip install -r requirements.txt` is ever running on the workers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your issue and use `PyPi` packages with [Beam](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/), I recommend you using a `setup.py` file, example :

```py
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    name="dataflow_job",
    version="0.0.1",
    install_requires=[
        'scrubadub==2.0.0'
    ],
    packages=find_packages(),
)
```

For example put this file at the root of the project.

Then in the command line that launches the `Beam` job with `Dataflow`, use the `setup_file` program argument :

```bash
python -m your_module.your_folder.main \
        --runner=DataflowRunner \
        --setup_file=./setup.py \
        ....
```

It's important to follow this to launch correctly your job :

- The runner of the job (maybe your local machine) should use a virtual env with the same packages installed (example with `2.45.0`) : `apache_beam==2.45.0` and `scrubadub==2.0.0`
  The versions of packages should be the same as the packages used by the workers. The runner will instantiate the job.
- Then the workers will use the packages given by the `setup.py` file (same versions as them used by the runner). In the `setup.py` you don't have to install Beam, because it's given the runtime environment.

Comment: I'm getting the same error using the `setup.py` command line flag

Comment: You have this error while creating Dataflow worker and in the worker log ?

Comment: Yes; here is what an example worker log looks like: 
`"/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 826, in _import_module return __import__(import_name) ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrubadub'`

Comment: Here is the command I'm running via the GCP CLI:
`python -m test_user.dataflow_beam_test --runner=DataflowRunner --setup_file = /home/test_user/setup.py`

Comment: And here is my setup.py file:
```from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    name="dataflow_job",
    version="0.0.1",
    install_requires=[
        'scrubadub==2.0.0'
    ],
    packages=find_packages(),
)```

Comment: One amendment to what I wrote above: the workers are getting created successfully, they're just not installing the required third party library.

Comment: Ok and in the runner part, are you sure having installed correctly this package in your virtual env ?

Comment: I see mostly `--requirements_file` being used (see https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/), but apparently `--setup_file` should work as well. Can you try using the former so we can try to narrow this down?

Comment: Hi Bruno, yes the two work well, I don't exactly remember what, previously I had an issue with `requirements` and `setup` was more stable. The `setup` is also needed for `Beam` having multiple `Python` files because the project should be packaged, I can centralize here the packages. I suspect that the problem here is the missing of  the needed `Python`  packages in the virtual env and the place where the `Beam` job is launched.

Comment: @MazlumTosun that was correct - the relevant Python packages were not in the virtual environment I was launching the job from. Marked as resolved - thank you!